# Form submit based on IP or Geolocation

Tags: php, geolocation

I need to create a form that submits to an email address based on the user's ip or geolocation. For example, if the user submits the form in Peru, it needs to send to a representative in that region; if user submit form in US, then submit to a rep in US, and so forth... Does anyone have any info. on this? It would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: ask the submitter, only 100% reliable way.

Comment: @robjb "Gears API (**Deprecated**)"

Answer (score 5):

The newer HTML5 standard has a [geolocation API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W3C_Geolocation_API).  There's a demo [here](http://html5demos.com/geo).

Answer (score 2):

Even though you can use [the geolocation API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W3C_Geolocation_API) of HTML5, the best possible way would be to ask the user in the form.

The user will have no reason to lie to you and will appreciate it much better then trying to figure out his location.